# About the Moment of Inertia of a rolling sphere on an incline

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

This is just a conceptual question I need to be clarified.

[image]

When I have to write down the equations for the dynamics of a rolling sphere over an incline (let's forget about the friction), I need, obviously, to take into account the rotational energy, hence I need the Momentum of Inertia.

Many times I read in notes that you take

$$I = \frac{2}{5} mR^2$$

Whilst in other exercises I noticed they instead use

$$I' = \frac{7}{5}mR^2$$

because they add $mR^2$ due to the parallel axis theorem, to $I$.

Why do they use two different approaches? $I'$ is referred at point P, whilst the first one is referred to $C$, I understand this. But how to choose?

What is the "correct" momentum when analyzing the rolling sphere over an incline motion? Which one shall I use when writing down the conservation of energy or Newton's laws?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are correct. This is basically a question of frame of reference.

In the first approach they split the kinetic energy in two parts:

1. a rotation around the symmetry axis of the sphere, i.e. with $I=\frac{2}{5}mR^2$, let's call the angular velocity: $\omega$
2. a translation down the slope with a velocity, $v=\omega R$ (assuming non-slipping motion)

In the second approach they consider the kinetic energy as rotation around the contact point.  In this case the rotational axis is not going through the center of the sphere and therefore the moment of inertia has to be modified, by adding $mR^2$. There is no additional "translational" kinetic energy in this approach

Both approaches are completely equivalent as you can see when you write down the kinetic energy:

$$E_\textrm{kin}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2\\
=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2R^2+\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{5}mR^2\omega^2\\
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{7}{5}mR^2\omega^2\\
=\frac{1}{2}I'^2\omega^2$$